# Getting "undefined method" when attempting to order the result of a Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.  I'm having trouble ordering results returned from this query:

```
@crypto_currencies = CryptoIndexCurrency
  .all
  .pluck("crypto_currency_id")
  .order(:name)
```

The `name` field is a valid member of the table from which I want to order.

```
cindex=# \d crypto_currencies;
                                            Table "public.crypto_currencies"
          Column          |            Type             |                           Modifiers
--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id                       | integer                     | not null default nextval('crypto_currencies_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                     | character varying           |
 symbol                   | character varying           |
 latest_market_cap_in_usd | bigint                      |
 latest_total_supply      | bigint                      |
 created_at               | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at               | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

Unfortunately whe I run the above I get the error:

```
undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x007fa3b2b27bd8>
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

That's right, `pluck` returns an array. Here is a note from documentation:

> Pluck returns an Array of attribute values type-casted to match the plucked column names

`where` and `order` and  other methods like that return `Relation` so that you can chain them. `pluck` should  be in the end.

Comment: Yeah but "name" is not an attribute of the crypto_index_currency table, it is an attribute of the "crypto_currencies" table (the one I listed in my question).  The way you wrote the clause above causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

Say you're trying to cook eggs for yourself -- you're trying to scramble an egg carton instead of the egg inside the carton.

`name` is a field of `CryptoCurrency`, but `.pluck` is returning an *array* of CryptoCurrency objects -- the array has no `name` field.

You have to get the specific CryptoCurrency array element by either iterating through the array (for example, using `.each... do`) or accessing an element by index (`@crypto_currencies[0]`).

For more tutorial information on how to access the elements of an array, either by [iteration](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Iterating+over+Arrays) or [by element](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements), please consult the official documentation.

Comment: Great so what is the code I would use to solve my problem?  A one liner would be absolutely fantastic.

Comment: I gave you examples already, but you've supplied no clue as to what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get the name of all cryptocurriencies? Are you trying to get the name of a specific cryptocurrency? If so, which one? I can write code. I cannot read minds.